# enum with factory pattern

Tags: java, enums

I have two solutions to create a new instance by enum type.

Both works, however, which one should I choose and why?

**version 1:**

```
public enum ColorName {
    Red(ColorRed.class),
    Green(ColorGreen.class),
    Blue(ColorBlue.class),


    ColorName(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    private final Class<?> clazz;

    public Class<?> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public Color createColor(String name) {

        Color c = null;

        try {
            c = (Color) this.clazz.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(name);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

**version 2:**

```
public enum ColorName {
    Red{
        @Override
        public Color newInstance(String name) {
            return new ColorRed(name);
        }
    },
    Green{
        @Override
        public Color newInstance(String name) {
            return new ColorGreen(name);
        }
    },
    Blue{
        @Override
        public Color newInstance(String name) {
            return new ColorBlue(name);
        }
    };

    public abstract Color createColor(String name);
}
```

In my opinion, **version 2** is better (and likely faster, type safe, no reflections, no need to have try..catch).

The only benefit in **version 1**: smaller code (only one factory method instead of one constructor for each enum).

Are there any other benefits using **version 1** instead of **version 2**?

Are there any better alternatives? Maybe by using `Supplier`?

Comment: Why do you need to invoke constructor through reflection in your first approach? Why not just have instance there (in enum constructor) or a supplier that returns such instance?

Comment: Could you provide a solution with `Supplier`? Would this be better than using version 1 or 2? Cannot see a solution for version 1 without using reflection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 functional approach:

```
public enum Color {

    RED(text -> new RedColor(text));
    BLUE(text -> new BlueColor(text));

    Function<String, Color> function;

    Color(Function function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

    Color getColor(String text) {
        return function.apply(text);
    }
}
```

I feel like this one is the "shortest" way to achieve your goal.

Comment: This is a nice solution and I guess it is even better than **version 2**. By the way, you can even replace the enums by using method reference: `RED(RedColor::new)`. A new instance of `RedColor` is only created when calling `RED.getColor("test")` not before. This is good. Thanks.